# Open a URL from an iOS app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xcode, cordova

I am using PhoneGap to create an iOS app. 
I am trying to create a javascript function so upon click of an icon in an html page, the app opens up a browser window with a URL associated with the icon.

```js
function launchIcon(pUrl, pIconID)
{
    window.open(pUrl,'_system','location=yes');//'_blank', "height=1024,width=1920");
    return false;
}
```

When I simulate the code in the iOS simulator, the browser window doesn't open and I get an error that says "Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999). 
Any insight into the error or a possible solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you set PhoneGap's whitelist to make sure your app is allowed to access the URL in question?

Comment: Yes, I updated access origin to this:

Comment: Yes, I updated access origin to this: <access origin="*" />

Comment: Can the iOS simulator connect to the internet?

Comment: did you install the inAppBrowserPlugin?